# How can I aggregate elements of list of lists to get one vector?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have list of lists (same lengths: n). How can I concatenate them, to get one vector of the same input length (n) ? For example I have:

```
[[1]] 
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[[2]] 
[1] "a" "a" NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[[3]]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA "d" "e" NA NA NA
```

I want to get:

```
"a" "a" NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA "d" "e" NA NA NA
```

I have tried:

```
Reduce('union',lapply(l,function(x){x$AB}))
```

But I got:

```
"a" NA "d" "e"
```

I want to get a vector with same length as the input `l[[1]]$AB`. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share you input data with `dput(x$AB)` (if `x$AB` is the name of your data object) ? That would help and clarify if your object is really a nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also perform row operation with conversion to a data.frame :

```r
list_obj <- list(rep(NA, 20), c("a", "a", rep(NA, 18)), c(rep(NA,16), "d", "e", NA, NA))
df_l <- as.data.frame(list_obj)
apply(df_l, 1, FUN = function(x) paste(ifelse(is.na(x), "", x), collapse = ""))
#>  [1] "a" "a" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "d" "e" "" 
#> [20] ""
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for `dplyr`'s `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)
mylist<-lapply(mylist,as,"character")
do.call(coalesce,mylist)
[1] "a" "a" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "d" "e" NA  NA  NA
```

NOTE: Using your exact example, the first element on the list is automatically interpreted as logical class because it's all `NA`s. I added row 2 in the code above to get around that by coercing all rows in the list into a `character` class.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, c(l, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] "a" "a" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "d" "e" NA  NA  NA
```

#### data

```
l <- list(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c("a", "a", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "d", "e", NA, NA, NA))
```

Comment: Your solution `do.call(pmax, c(list_obj, na.rm = TRUE))` posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29634492/8245406) works. I am closing as duplicate.

Comment: I have upvoted the one in the link, believing that it's the right place to do it. But I can reopen/upvote this one/close :(.

Comment: It is a dupe but the question is not very clear especially wiith the `x$AB`

Answer (score 0):

You could coerce list to a data frame and use `ifelse` case handling like this:

```
apply(as.data.frame(l), 1, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, x[!is.na(x)]))
# [1] "a" "a" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
# [17] NA  NA  "d" "e" NA  NA  NA
```

---

*Data*

```
l <- list(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c("a", "a", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "d", "e", NA, NA, NA))
```