# Merging two columns into one based on value

Tags: r

I have a dataset with two columns containing the following: an indicator number and a hashcode

The only problem is that the columns have the same name, but the value can switch columns.
Now I want to merge the columns and keep the number (I don't care about the hashcode)

I saw this question: [Merge two columns into one in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634425/merging-two-columns-into-one-in-r)
and I tried the `coalesce()` function, but that is only for having NA values. Which I don't have. I looked at the unite function, but according to the cheat sheet documentation [documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3) that doesn't what I'm looking for

My next try was the `filter_at` and other filter functions from the dplyr package [Documentation here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter_all.html)

But that only leaves 150 data points while at the start I have 61k data points.
Code of filter_at I tried:

```
data <- filter_at(data,vars("hk","hk_1"),all_vars(.>0))
```

I assumed that a #-string shall not be greater than 0, which seems to be true, but it removes more than intented.

I would like to keep hk or hk_1 value which is a number. The other one (the hash) can be removed. Then I want a new column which only contains those numbers.

---

Sample data

My data looks like this:

```
HK|HK1
190|#SP0839
190|#SP0340
178|#SP2949
#SP8390|177
#SP2240|212
```

What I would like to see:

```
HK
190
190
178
177
212
```

I hope this provides an insight into the data. There are more columns like description, etc which makes that 190 at the start are not doubles.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a sample of what your data looks like.

Comment: @Helper: Can you post sample data?

Comment: @XXavier @@user2332849 I added a data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can replace all the values that start with `"#"` to `NA` and then use `coalesce` to select non-NA value between `HK` and `HK1`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(~as.character(replace(., grepl("^#", .), NA))) %>%
  mutate(HK = coalesce(HK, HK1)) %>%
  select(HK)

#     HK
#1   190
#2   190
#3   178
#4   177
#5   212
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(HK = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("#SP2240", 
"#SP8390", "178", "190"), class = "factor"), HK1 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("#SP0340", "#SP0839", "#SP2949", 
"177", "212"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```